# DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter to delay loading a tableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I want to load one table view cell for 2 seconds, then remove that cell and replace it with a new custom cell that will have downloaded content. Basically I am faking a "response" from a bot. I am supposed to delay the response for 2 seconds. Don't ask..its part of my sprint.

in cellForRowAt: I have the first cell (LoadingCell) dequeued.

I know I need to destroy the data in the cell then remove it from indexPAth after, can I use DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter to delay the response cell from populating in the tableView ?

Comment: Yes, you're in control of the tableView content and behavior. Just change your model and reload when you're ready.

Comment: Thank you! I just had a thought, that creating a whole new cell is too much work. I can delay the UI elements in the cell until I need them and show the initial stuff first. The last thing then would be to make sure the first UI doesn't get called when someone scrolls. And to have a default UI state for all the cells.